# JetBrains Rider Shows Mono Not Installed

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 and have installed mono by using the below commands

```
sudo apt install mono-devel
sudo apt install mono-complete
sudo apt install mono-dbg
sudo apt install referenceassemblies-pcl
sudo apt install ca-certificates-mono
sudo apt install mono-xsp4
```

however, when I launch Rider and choose new solution -> Xamarin Application I see a red line stating Mono can not be found.

If I follow the link to install mono - I have already run all of the commands listed.  What must I do in order to develope Xamarin with Rider on Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried to follow official instructions? https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207335749-Using-Rider-under-Linux-prerequisites

Comment: @MitchMahoney do you found a solution?

Comment: @basilkot - I was unable to find a solution and I never heard back from Jetbrains support.  I ended up using Hackintosh in a VM to achieve what I was after.  It was DEF slow, but it served the purpose.